# FREETDS freebcp default value in format file

Tags: freetds, freebcp

Is it possible to have a default value for a column when data is blank in format file definition? Here is the command I am using:

```
freebcp MYDB..my_tablein temp_data -b 10000 -fmyown.fmt -SSQL_SERVER
```

I have format definition in `myown.fmt`.

Comment: Can you include your format definition? Also, shouldn't there be spaces like this: `freebcp MYDB..my_tablein temp_data -b 10000 -f myown.fmt -S SQL_SERVER`? Do you have a default value set in SQL Server for the column in question, or are you trying to specify it through `freebcp`?

Comment: I dont have default value setup for a column in SQL Server. I would want to do that in bcp step in format-file